# UITextField from enterBackground to enterForeground,app crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

custom UITextField: In the click TextField input,After the keyborad popup,enter the background to get enter foreground again,The app crash!

if you don't click TextField input,background or foreground conversion ,It is normal;Part of the code:

```
@implementatio BKSearchViewController
    - (void)setNavgationView {
        BKSearchBar *searchBar = [[BKSearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 27, kScreenWidth - 90, 30)];
        searchBar.placeholder = @"输入昵称/拜托号";
        searchBar.delegate = self;
        [searchBar setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
        [searchBar setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeySearch];
        [searchBar setPlaceholderColor:kcallColor(@"a4a4a4")];
        [searchBar setPlaceholderFont:kFont(14)];
        [searchBar addTarget:self action:@selector(SearchTextFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
        [navgationView addSubview:searchBar];
    }
    @end

    //BKSearchBar The key code
                @implementation BKSearchBar
                - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
                {
                    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
                    if (self) {
                        // 设置背景
                        self.backgroundColor = kcallColor(@"7d1d57");
                        self.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
                        // 设置内容 -- 垂直居中
                        self.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
                        [self UI];
                    }
                    return self;
                }
    - (void)UI{
        // 设置左边显示一个放大镜
        UIImageView *leftView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        omit...
        //右边的view
        UIImageView *rightView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        omit...
    }
            - (CGRect)placeholderRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds{
                CGRect rect = CGRectMake(self.leftView.right, (self.height - 24) / 2, bounds.size.width, 14);
                return rect;
            }
            - (void)clearText{
                self.text = nil;
            }
            - (void)setPlaceholderColor:(UIColor *)color{
                [self setValue:color forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
            }
            - (void)setPlaceholderFont:(UIFont *)font{
                [self setValue:font forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.font"];
            }
```

Comment: `background or foreground conversion`? cant get your ques and show the original code don't show any image for code.

Comment: do not post screenshot of code in question, post code directly instead!

Comment: have you implemented UISearchBar delegate ?? if yes please post that code so we can get idea whats going wrong.

Comment: where is your method `SearchTextFieldDidChange` ? can you post that one also ?

Comment: @CodeChanger ok,Has been updated！and BKSearchBar key code；Have add, and protocol implementation agent

Comment: @NegHao Din't get you what are you trying to say ?

Comment: @vaibhav yes, if you click TextField input,background or foreground conversion ,is crash。I preliminary think: no 'textfield' directly lead to the collapse of, but 'textfield' input events clashed with other events

Comment: @CodeChanger sorry! I already to update my question description

Comment: again please clarify your ques what you want, cant understand you.

Comment: thank you. The problem is resolved！because of the runtime！You can see my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank all！The problem is resolved！because of the runtime！

```
+ (void)swizzleInstanceMethod:(Class)class originSelector:(SEL)originSelector otherSelector:(SEL)otherSelector
{
    Method otherMehtod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, otherSelector);
    Method originMehtod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originSelector);
    // 交换2个方法的实现
    method_exchangeImplementations(otherMehtod, originMehtod);
}
```